# Filling up a numpy array using data from a list

Tags: python, performance

I am looking to optimize the nested for-loops shown in the code below.

I have a list, `mixtures`, that contains points that represent 1 Gaussian Mixture (GM) on each line. My goal is to run a function `kl_divergence` between all combinations of GM's (with i≠j) and store the results in an array `PxP`.

*Note: The following* `mixtures` *list  is a simplified version of the actual list. In my original code, I am working with a lot more data.*

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture

def kl_divergence(gmm_i, gmm_j, n_samples=10**5):
    X = gmm_i.sample(n_samples)
    log_p_i = gmm_i.score_samples(X[0])
    log_p_j = gmm_j.score_samples(X[0])
    return log_p_i.mean() - log_p_j.mean()


mixtures = [[[1, 3, 4, 7], [3, 5, 9, 2], [4, 3, 6, 1], [4, 3, 6, 3]],
            [[3, 4, 8, 2], [3, 6, 3, 7], [2, 6, 8, 4]],
            [[4, 8, 9, 3], [2, 6, 5, 8], [2, 5, 3, 5]],
            [[4, 9, 0, 2], [2, 4, 8, 3], [9, 8, 2, 3], [2, 6, 8, 3]]]
#Note: Each line has a different number of points

P_comp = len(mixtures)
PxP = np.zeros((P_comp, P_comp), dtype=int)

for row_i, GM_i in enumerate(mixtures):    #Loop through mixtures using i
    gmm_i = GaussianMixture(n_components=1).fit(GM_i)
    for row_j, GM_j in enumerate(mixtures): #Loop through mixtures using j
        if GM_i is not GM_j: #Skip if same mixture
            gmm_j = GaussianMixture(n_components=1).fit(GM_j)
            PxP[row_i, row_j] = kl_divergence(gmm_i, gmm_j) #Store result at index (row_i, row_j)

print("PxP\n", PxP)
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview! Looks like you instantiate a `GaussianMixture` over and again for any given element of `mixtures` - is that a cheap operation? Did you try and find out which part of the consumes most time with `a lot more data`?

Comment: Are you working with so much data that space might start to become a problem, or "just" so much data that performance might be significant?

Comment: @greybeard Here are some performance figures: `kl_divergence(gmm_i, gmm_j)` runs in **45ms** on average. Preparing a GM `gmm_i` or `gmm_j` takes anywhere between **10ms** and **1000ms**, and depends on how many points are in `row_i` or `row_j`.

Comment: @Ninetails Memory hasn't been an issue yet, so it's purely a performance issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code to establish `PxP` should be in a function of its own, featuring a [doc string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring) and comments where necessary (why not use `GaussianMixture(covariance_type ='spherical')`?)
Same goes for `kl_divergence()`: when(/why?) is `n_samples=10**5` appropriate?

From eyeballing your code, it would seem that you instantiate a `GaussianMixture()` not just once for each mixture, but `(len(mixtures))²`?  times.
Try to turn `mixtures` into `GaussianMixture` upfront: `mixtures = [GaussianMixture().fit(mix) for mix in mixtures]` (`n_components=1` is default - do you need `covariance_type='full'`?).

Comment: The improvement I got in computation time after I turned `mixtures` into `GaussianMixture` upfront is unbelievable. I was expecting a 1.5-2x boost in performance but it turned out to be much more: **30x**. Regarding the doc string and comments, I believe you are right. It will help explain/clarify the parameters I'm using.